# jenkins in cloudbees The remote end hung up unexpectedly

Tags: git, jenkins, bitbucket, cloudbees

I have repository in bitbucket and I want to config this repository with Cloudbees that run jenkins as service

my problem is when I try to run the Jenkins build i get this error message

> Error cloning remote repo 'origin' : Could not clone
>   ssh://myRepo@bitbucket.org/myRepo/app1.git
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Could not clone
>   ssh://myRepo@bitbucket.org/myRepo/app1.git    at
>   org.jenkinsci.plugins.gitclient.CliGitAPIImpl.clone(CliGitAPIImpl.java:219)
>     at hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:1001)     at
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitSCM$2.invoke(GitSCM.java:942)   at
>   hudson.FilePath$FileCallableWrapper.call(FilePath.java:2236)  at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:118)     at
>   hudson.remoting.UserRequest.perform(UserRequest.java:48)  at
>   hudson.remoting.Request$2.run(Request.java:326)   at
>   hudson.remoting.InterceptingExecutorService$1.call(InterceptingExecutorService.java:72)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
>     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
>     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722) Caused by:
>   hudson.plugins.git.GitException: Command "git clone --progress -o
>   origin ssh://myRepo@bitbucket.org/myRepo/app1.git
>   /scratch/jenkins/workspace/myRepo automation build" returned status
>   code 128: stdout: Cloning into '/scratch/jenkins/workspace/myRepo
>   automation build'...
>
> **stderr: Warning: Permanently added 'bitbucket.org,207.223.240.182'
>   (RSA) to the list of known hosts. Permission denied (publickey).
>   fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

I think the problem is that I need to add bitbucket to "list of know host", but I dont know how to do that on Jenkin which hosting in Cloudbees server.

Answer (score 3):

Go to /configure and you should see a CloudBees SSH key in the configuration list.  Add that to the list of keys for your BitBucket repo to give Jenkins access to the repo.

Comment: I already made that, the problem is i think with the list of know host

Comment: No, this is clearly an authentication problem. To debug this try adding a build step which says "ssh -v bitbucket.org" in Jenkins. Try the same from your local computer where you have a valid key and compare the output.